# How can I view all zones in a an Orchard theme?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm trying to learn orchard. The theme machine has many zones to place widgets. Is there a way through the browser to see all the zones available and their location on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to see the zones is to look at the thememachines layout.cshtml file and see where each of them get placed.  You could add a widget to each zone like pszmyd recommends as well and then turn on the developer/experimental feature and you will see the name of the zone when you leave your cursor over it.

Answer (score 1):

The zones collapse if there is no content inside, so if you'd want to see all of them you should place some content in every zone. I'd recommend placing the simplest widget - HtmlWidget in every zone.

You can add widgets to zones from Widgets pane in admin Dashboard. Just choose your widget, add some content, choose the right zone from the drop-down and hit Save (and repeat that for every zone you'd like to see).

If you just want to see the image of all zones and read something aboth them - try [this docs article](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Anatomy-of-a-theme.ashx).